Why do powers of $\operatorname{sinc}$ converge to a Gaussian function?
I am looking to find an intuition for how powers of the $\text{sinc}$ function behave. Just for context, the $\text{sinc}$ function I'm looking at is the "unnormalized" one:
$$
\text{sinc}(x) =
\begin{cases}
    1  &\text{if}\, x = 0\\
    \frac {\sin x} {x}  &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Consider this sequence of functions:
$$
f_n(x):= \text{sinc} \left( \sqrt{\dfrac{3}{n}} \cdot x \right) ^ {n}
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. As $n \to \infty$, my conjecture is that $f_n \to g$ uniformly, where $g$ is a Gaussian function:
$$
g(x) := \exp {\left( -x^2 / 2 \right)}
$$
Expanding the Taylor series of $f_n$ and $g$ around $x = 0$, I obtain:
$$
f_n(x) = 1 
- \frac{1}{2} x^2 
+ \left( \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{20n} \right) x^4 
- \left( \frac{1}{48} - \frac{1}{40n} + \frac{1}{105n^2} \right) x^6 
+ \left( \frac{1}{384} - \frac{1}{160n} + \frac{101}{16800n^2} - \frac{3}{1400n^3} \right) x^8 + O(x^{10})
\\
g(x) 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{2^k k!}}
= 1 
- \frac{1}{2} x^2 
+ \frac{1}{8} x^4 
- \frac{1}{48} x^6 
+ \frac{1}{384} x^8 + O(x^{10}) \\
$$
(I expanded the series for $f_n$ by way of reference to this question & using Wolfram Alpha.)
I can see that the terms with $n$ in the denominator in the series coefficients for $f_n$ will vanish as $n \to \infty$, leaving only the leading term. Inspecting the first dozen or so of those leading terms confirms they equal the coefficients in the series for $g$, reinforcing my suspicion that $f_n \to g$ uniformly.
But simply comparing the "first few" coefficients by inspection leaves me feeling... unenlightened. Is there an elegant way to prove that $f_n \to g$ uniformly? Would it be sufficient to prove that the non-vanishing terms in the coefficients of the series expansion for $f_n$ will continue to equal $\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k k!}$ out to $k=\infty$? And if so, how does one approach that proof?
(And, by the way: is there any particular underlying intuition for why the argument of $\text{sinc}$ must be scaled by a factor of $\sqrt{3}$?)
More broadly: are there some more general mathematical concepts I can leverage to better understand what's going on? Looking at the generality of results like the central limit theorem, as well as questions like this - is it just incidental that $\text{sinc}$ was the function I happened to be messing around with this one particular lazy Sunday, and actually this type of convergence to a Gaussian happens for a much wider class of sequences of functions? My interest here is purely recreational (and this isn't "for" anything in particular)... so more abstract answers / hand-wavey "proofs" / generalized discussion / nudges in the right direction for me to run with the rest of the way are all very welcome. ;)
Thank you!

Your issue is explainable in a clean way with Fourier transform and spline functions.
Let us denote by $\chi$ the characteristic function $\chi_{[-\tfrac12,\tfrac12]}$ of interval $[-\tfrac12,\tfrac12]$ (also called "rectangular function", especially in Signal Processing).
Fourier transform

maps $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$  onto $\chi(u)$ (reference here) for a certain normalization of Fourier Transform).

Therefore :

maps $\operatorname{sinc}^n(x)$ (ordinary power) onto $s_n(u):=\chi^{*n}(u)$ (convolution power), which happens to be a special kind of spline function.

It is known that $s_n$ (conveniently rescaled) converges to a gaussian curve, when $n \to \infty$ (see how this convergence is quick on Fig. 1 below for $n=4$).
As the Inverse Fourier Transform of a gaussian function is a gaussian function, coming back in the original space of variable $x$, we have established the result : we have indeed a gaussian function.
Besides, there is a handy explicit formula expressing
$s_n:=\chi^{*n}$ given here expressing it as a spline function (with a shift because in the reference just given, interval $[0,1]$ is used instead of interval $[-\tfrac12,\tfrac12]$).
For example, for $n=4$ we have:
$$s_4(x)=\chi^{*4}(x)=(x+2)_+^3-4(x+1)_+^3+6(x)_+^3-4(x-1)_+^3+(x-2)_+^3$$
(please note alternate sign binomial coefficients)
where $x_+:=\max(0,x)$ (called "ramp function" in Signal Processing).
See for example the representative curve of $\chi^{*4}$ (Fig. below) obtained with the following Sage program :
 r(x)=max_symbolic(0,x)^3
 f(x)=r(x+2)-4*r(x+1)+6*r(x)-4*r(x-1)+r(x-2)
 g=plot(f(x),(x,-3,3))
 g+=plot(4*exp(-x^2/0.7071),(x,-3,3),color='red')
 show(g)


Fig. 1 : The (blue) spline curve of $s_4$, and its excellent approximation by a (red) gaussian curve (see program).
Remark : The blue curve above is in fact polynomial by intervals with at most third degree expressions on each interval $[k,k+1]$, $k=-2,-1,0,1$ of so-called Bezier curves.
Important remark : Almost all this can be explained in a probabilistic framework : $\chi^{*n}$ can be interpreted as the pdf of the sum $S_n$ of $n$ uniformly distributed independent random variables on $[-\tfrac12,\tfrac12]$, and it is known (Central Limit Theorem, that you have mentionned in your question) that $\tfrac{1}{n}S_n$ converges (in law) to the standard gaussian distribution $N(0,1)$. (please note that multiplication by $\tfrac{1}{n}$ is equivalent to a normalization).

Thank you! :) I don't have much background in signal processing, but I do have some (very modest) amount in probability theory. The connection to the Fourier transform is what I was missing, I think.

Having done some additional reading on your "Important remark" since Sunday: I noted that the Fourier transform for $\text{rect}$ works also in the other direction. So if I take the essential part of your answer, but I consider that your mapping from $\text{sinc}(x) \to \chi (u)$ is also the Inverse Fourier Transform... then as you remarked, the $\chi (u)$ can all be thought of as pdfs of uniform random variables; the convolution $\chi ^{n*}$ = the pdf of their sum; CLT -> the limiting pdf is Gaussian; the characteristic function of a uniform random variable = $\text{sinc}$!

So basically, thinking about my question in probability theory terms that I'm more familiar with... I can construe my question as, I was already in characteristic function space, multiplying $\text{sinc}$ with itself, and ending up with a Gaussian (whose Fourier transform is itself). And I can construe your answer as, if I look at the $\chi (u)$ which are the pdfs of i.i.d. uniform RVs whose characteristic functions are $\text{sinc} (x)$, then I am really just observing the central limit theorem. :)

P.S. This answers the part of my question about "... a much wider class of sequences of functions ..." too. ;) For example, $h_n(x) := ( \frac{2n}{2n+x^2} )^n \to g(x)$ for the exact same reason. Glossing over some details, the $h_n$ are scaled versions of the characteristic function of some RV*/the Fourier transform of some function which is the pdf of that RV, to which the CLT also applies.
*a Laplace distribution, but I only know that bc I picked it out of a hat just for the sake of that example heh.

Very thorough comments on the probability interpretation. See for example dias 63, etc. in this nice powerpoint presentation.
